# An SSL error when npm run dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

```
➜  npm run dev
...
 Starting dev server...
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2768ms
 11:30:11 AM
 Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

I run the `npm run dev`command，successful , but browser console put a error:

> Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. https://localhost:8080/app.js

Why load the app.js by `https`?

my npm version: 5.5.1

Comment: Your server runs on http, thus you cannot connect to with https. Did you configure https somewhere in your configuration files ?

Comment: no, I did not configure https

Answer (score 0):

**solve it !**
comment this `meta` in html:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />`